# Loading google map only once in android

Tags: android, google-maps

From other posts, I have seen that when I call getMapAsync() Android gets all info about a map object for me and then I can access it in OnMapReadyCallback. This is all straight forward.

I have an app with one Activity, 4 fragments, and a View model. I am implementing a MapView in one fragment. The problem I have is that every time I navigate back to the fragment with map view I am loading map object from network again. Is this true and if so how do I only load it once throughout the application.

I would like to have the mapObject in my ViewModel but it seems that I can only load this map object via the MapView and I should NOT have map view in my ViewModel.

Another solution I tried was to create a Map view in the main activity. This MapView was used simply to load the API's from the network only once but I have no way of checking this.

My next test is to use Wireshark to see how often the info is taken from the network?

If anyone has experience with this, please help.